# Programmatically create new site collecttion with new content database error. Object Same ID. SP2013

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sharepoint

I need to create site collections automatically in a Timer Job. This functionality is working correctly when it comes to a single content database.

But a content database has its limitations and need time to create the site collection check the limit and in case of exceeding the specified limit have to create another content database and use it.

The creation of this content dababase is working:

```
public static SPContentDatabase CriarContentDataBase(string server, string contentName, SPSite site)
{
    SPContentDatabase content = new SPContentDatabase();
    content = site.WebApplication.ContentDatabases.Add(server, contentName, null, null, 35, 40, 0);
    content.Update();
    site.WebApplication.Update();
    return content;
}
```

The problem is time to create the site collection, I am using the overload `SPContentDataBase.Add(// parameters)` method:

```
SPContentDatabase currentContentDataBase = getCurrentContentDataBase(site);

using (SPSite newSite = currentContentDataBase.Sites.Add(siteCollectionURL, titulo, null, 1046, 15, TEMPLATE_NAME, loginUsuarioGestorConteudo, nomeUsuarioGestorConteudo, emailUsuarioGestorConteudo, "", "", "", currentContentDataBase.Server, currentContentDataBase.Name, null, null))
            {

                // more code
            }
```

This call returns me an exception of SPException type with the following message:

```
The attach operation cannot continue because another object in this farm already contains the same ID. Each object in a farm must have a unique ID. In order to proceed with the attach operation you must assign a new ID to this database. To attach this database with a new ID, use the Mount-SPContentDatabase command with the -AssignNewDatabaseId parameter. Note that if this new database and an existing database contain the same site collections, attaching this database will likely result in orphaned site collections due to conflicts between the two databases.
```

Can someone tell me how to do it you have as to create the content database I modify this ID?

Thank you.

Comment: where you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Central Admin > Application Management > Manage Content Database and see your how many content DB does your Web Application has.

If there are more than one, please check If the name or id is same with the new one you tried to create.